# Oauth and then get twitter feed in same page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

I am using angularjs and I am trying to get my Twitter authentication and timeline code to run in the same page rather than how I currently have it set up with 2 pages.

currently I have it setup like so:

My controllers:

```
    .controller('connectCtrl', function connectCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
  OAuth.initialize('SYd6rvZZTLQT-oJxWOeNctFuUyA');
    $scope.connect = function() {
        OAuth.popup("twitter", function(err, res) {
            if (err) return alert(err);
            $rootScope.twitter = res;
            $location.path('/timeline');
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
})
.controller('timelineCtrl', function timelineCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.twitter.get('/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json').done(function(data) {
        $scope.tw_timeline = data;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
})
```

and then my html:

timeline.html:

```
  <a href="#/home" class="btn btn-success">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; home
                        </a>
<ul id="timeline" ng-repeat="entry in tw_timeline">
    <li>
        <img class="thumb" src="{{entry.user.profile_image_url}}" />
        <span class="content">
            <span class="author">{{entry.user.name}}</span>
            <span class="text">{{entry.text}}</span>
            </span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

and my connect.html page:

```
<h3>Connect with twitter to see your home timeline</h3>
<button ng-click='connect()' class="btn btn-primary">
    <img src="https://oauth.io/api/providers/twitter/logo" /> connect with twitter
</button>
```

This works fine, but I want to integrate it all in my homepage where I have other stuff as well. I have been working on it most of the day and I am getting nowhere.
Ill either get issues with Twitter being undefined or some other error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.